# Send email with System.Net.Mail

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to send email with System.Net.Mail.

I use this code.

```
 string[] emails = Email.Split(',');
 MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
 message.From = new MailAddress("doc@mysite.net");
 foreach (var em in emails)
   message.To.Add(new MailAddress(em));
 message.Subject = "ثبت مدارک جدید";
 message.Body = DNameTextBox.Text + Environment.NewLine + DMobileTextBox.Text + 
  Environment.NewLine + DEmailTextBox.Text + Environment.NewLine 
  + DsubjectTextBox.Text + Environment.NewLine + DDescTextBox.Text;
 {
     HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
     for (int i = 0; i <= hfc.Count - 1; i++)    // CHECK THE FILE COUNT.
      {
        HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
        if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
          message.Attachments.Add(
            new Attachment(hpf.InputStream, Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName))
          );
       }
      }

      SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("mail.site.com", 25);

      //to authenticate we set the username and password properites on the SmtpClient
      smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("doc@mysite.net", "000");
      smtp.Send(message);
```

It sent the email, but my problem is that it sent 20 emails.

Why did `smtp.Send(message)` send multiple emails?

Comment: You add the recipient based on `Email.Split(',')`. What is in `Email`? May it be, that there are twenty comma separated adresses?

Comment: Yes, I have 2 email for sent email. (sms@mysite.com,mysite@gmail.com)

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on `smtp.Send`? How many times gets it hit. If you only have two (2) addresses in Email, then it probably is hit ten times.

Comment: Yes, i put. it is hit 5 second.

Comment: Ok, it gets there in 5 seconds, but how many times?

Comment: Sorry. I have two emailaddress that want to send emails for them. I use breakpoint on `smtp.Send`, it hit one time. but send 20 emails for every mail address.

Comment: There is not enough information to see where the issue is. To debug, remove "foreach (var em in emails) message.To.Add(new MailAddress(em));" and add only "message.To.Add(new MailAddress("sms@mysite.com"));" and see how many emails you will get. If you get 20 emails - it means you call that code x20 times. If you get only 1 email - it means string[] emails is incorrect and has more than 2 emails.

Comment: Thanks, I remove foreach but get 20 emails again.

Comment: are you sure that it sends 20 emails to both of your address..!!!

Comment: Yes, I check mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

This because you have added multiple address in to address. So it will send email to all the to email address.

See the following code.

```
 foreach (var em in emails)
   message.To.Add(new MailAddress(em));
```

Comment: I want send email for 2 mailaddress. when check mailbox i get new email every 2 second .(get 20 email when send a email )

Comment: First of all your english and requirement is not clear. Another thing I don't know why you given minus point for answers. I was just trying to help you. See whatever recipient you send it will send if you send it to two it will send two emails. Check now many time SMTP.Send is called.

Comment: Yes but if you have two address in your message.To. part  it will definitely send two email. Because this how email works like in gmail if you put two email address in to field then it will send email to both email address same way it will go here. I don't know why you are not understanding this simple basic thing.